# What is the disease called "Tsurarekia (ツラレキア)"?

Tags: japanese-language, kinos-journey

In the episode 2 of Kino no Tabi, Kino hunts a rabbit for the three starving men. The men are so hungry that they say they would like to eat it raw rather than waiting for it to be cooked. Then Kino replies:

> I cannot allow that. It would be terrible if you were infected by **Tsurarekia** or something.
>   ダメです。**ツラレキア**にでもかかったら、 とんでもないことになる。

I searched for it in Google, but there were no results.
So, what is this "tsurarekia" thing?

[image: scene were "tsurarekia" appears]

Comment: Weirdly, the corresponding line in the light novel (vol 2, p. 20) is 「ダメです。ツラレミアにでもかかったら、とんでもないことになりますよ」, i.e. it uses the correct spelling of "tularemia" (ツラレミア _tsuraremia_). No idea why that would be changed for the anime; perhaps the voice actor just flubbed her lines.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is an error in subtitles or if they slightly altered the real disease's name, but either way I think they are referring to Tularemia, which is pronounced as tsuraremia (ツラレミア) in Japanese.

From [the English Wikipedia article for Tularemia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tularemia), bold emphasis is my own:

> Tularemia (also known as Pahvant Valley plague, **rabbit fever**, deer fly
>   fever, and Ohara's fever) is a serious infectious disease caused by
>   the bacterium Francisella tularensis. A Gram-negative, nonmotile
>   coccobacillus, the bacterium has several subspecies with varying
>   degrees of virulence. The most important of those is F. tularensis
>   tularensis (Type A), which is **found in lagomorphs (rabbits and similar
>   animals)** in North America, and it is **highly virulent in humans and
>   domestic rabbits**. F. tularensis palaearctica (Type B) occurs mainly in
>   aquatic rodents (beavers, muskrats) in North America and in **hares and
>   small rodents** in northern Eurasia. It is less virulent for humans and
>   rabbits. The primary vectors are ticks and deer flies, but the disease
>   can also be spread through other arthropods. The disease is named
>   after Tulare County, California.

From [the corresponding Japanese Wikipedia article](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%87%8E%E5%85%8E%E7%97%85), to show the Japanese pronunciation:

> アメリカ合衆国カリフォルニア州トゥーレアリ郡（w:Tulare County, California）で発見されたことからツラレミア
>   (tularemia)

Which translates to...

> ツラレミア (tsuraremia, Tularemia) comes from the fact that it was
>   discovered in Tulare County, California.